# Bind Bootstrap Radio Button To Angular Property

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having troubles getting a bootstrap radio box selection to bind into an angular property.

Here is what I have, it is not working.

HTML BOOTSTRAP

```
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-success active">
            <input type="radio" value="bill" ng-model="newItemType" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Insert New Bill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
          </label>
          <label" class="btn btn-success ">
            <input type="radio" value="coin" ng-model="newItemType" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Insert New Coin <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>  
          </label>
        </div>
```

ANGULAR JAVASCRIPT

```
var CurrencyInventoryBillController = function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.newItemType = "NOT SELECTED";

    //TRIGGERED ON BUTTON CLICK. ALERT SHOWS 'NOT SELECTED' REGARDLESS OF WHICH RADIO BTN IS SELECTED
    $scope.insertNewCurrencyItem = function()
    {
        alert($scope.newItemType);
    }

}
```

Why is the VALUE and NG-MODEL directives not changing the SCOPE variable in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
$scope.newItemType = 'bill';

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='bill'}" > 
     <input type="radio" value="bill" ng-model="newItemType"> Insert New Bill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
  </label> 
  <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='coin'}" >
    <input type="radio" value="coin" ng-model="newItemType"> Insert New Coin <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Update: [Here is the link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paila/2k6dkdwg/)

Comment: You can add ng-change='insertNewCurrencyItem()' to inputs to see the model changing on selection

Comment: Just tried this and it does NOT change the scope variable

Comment: It highlights the right button when i change the scope variable in the ass end, but clicking the buttons do not actually change the scopr variable

Comment: Did u get a chance to look at the fiddle

Comment: Interesting, it seems to work in the fiddle, but when i copied your code straight onto my website, it seemed to not work.  I will try it again tonight with the code from the fiddle, and see if i cant get those value and ng-model bindings to work again.  thanks for the checkup

Answer (score 3):

I aborted trying to get the bindings to work, and went with another approach, changing the values in the angular scope via the ng-click method inline in the html

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='bill'}" ng-click="newItemType='bill'" > 
         <input type="radio"> Insert New Bill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
      </label> 
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='coin'}" ng-click="newItemType='coin'" >
        <input type="radio"> Insert New Coin <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

Notice the ng-click event sets the newItemType to coin or bill.  This approach is imperfect, but it works for now until someone can figure out how to bind radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='bill'}">
        <input type="radio" value="bill" ng-model="newItemType" name="options">Insert New Bill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='coin'}">
        <input type="radio" value="coin" ng-model="newItemType" name="options">Insert New Coin <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span> 
      </label>
    </div>

    <br/>
    
    {{newItemType}}

  </div>

</div>
```

You have it you just have to change your class `active` to actually see it.

```
   <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='bill'}">
        <input type="radio" value="bill" ng-model="newItemType" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Insert New Bill <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-success" ng-class="{'active':newItemType=='coin'}">
        <input type="radio" value="coin" ng-model="newItemType" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Insert New Coin <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>  
      </label>
    </div>

 <br/>
 {{newItemType}}
```

Comment: This is just a copy of the above answer.